# How to extract traffic signs from a photograph?

Tags: image-processing, filters

What image analysis techniques can I use to extract the traffic signs from an image such as the one below?

[image: Exterior shot of a metropolitan roadside]

Edit:

After Anisotropic diffusion: The background that i don't want gets cleared a little

[image]

After Dilation :

[image]

Thresholding after Diffusion : Not able to figure out the best thresholding for this purpose

[image]

However i am not able to figure out how to remove the background?

Edit : i just want these parts of my image

[image]

Taking another input image :

[image]

Applying median filtering and edge detection :

[image]

After Bottom hat filtering:

[image]

**How do i isolate the road signs please help?**

Comment: To me, "traffic signal" means a lit up device http://www.justsymbol.com/images/traffic-signal-sign-6.png , not a sign.  Do you mean only signs?

Comment: Yes only the signs

Comment: What approach have you tried yourself?

Comment: Yes i do have templates

Comment: Have edited @mauritis

Comment: I don't know if you meant to do so but you had chosen perfect image, since it has 4 traffic signs (one on the floor) one is not a real one since it is a sign for parking, and only the one of the zebra crossing is relevant here true? what if you have Ads what then do you do?

Comment: what if the sign's are viewed from a non-frontal angle ?

Comment: I am non considering that case because all the images i have are of frontal angle only

Comment: I just cam across [this paper](http://www.academia.edu/2761792/Improved_efficiency_of_Road_Sign_Detection_and_Recognition_by_employing_Kalman_filter)

Comment: This [publication](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/339710955_Automatic_Signboard_Detection_from_Natural_Scene_Image_in_Context_of_Bangladesh_Google_Street_View) on signboard detection might help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you try something simple like correlation?

(**EDIT**). The idea behind correlation is to use a template (in your case a trained road sign sample), and compare it to every position in the test image. The comparison operation I've used to generate the images below is called normalized [cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalized_cross-correlation). Roughly speaking, you standardize (mean=0, standard deviation=1) the pixels in the template and the image part you want to match, multiply them pixel by pixel, and calculate the mean value of the products. This way you get a "match score", i.e. a measure of similarity between the template and the test image at every position in the test image. The position with the best match (highest correlation) is the most probably candidate for the position of the road sign.  (Actually, I've used the Mathematica function [CorrelationDistance](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CorrelationDistance.html) to generate the image below, which is 1 - (normalized correlation). So the darkest spot in the match image corresponds to the best match).

I don't have any other templates, so I simple cropped the sign from the second picture you posted:

[image]

Even though the template is rotated slightly, cross correlation still looks usable

[image]

and the best match is found at the right position:

[image]

(You'd need multiple scaled versions of each template to detect signs at any size, of course)

Comment: @nikie: Could you explain the process you used?

Comment: Yeah that would help a bit more . The idea seems good

Comment: @vini If you have templates and you're trying to find instances of it in your image, cross-correlation is the most natural approach and should be among the first approaches you try. Here's an answer [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1097/77) (Mathematica code) and [another on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8594330/616736) (MATLAB code) where I use this approach.

Comment: It is amazing how different would be the method to do so in our days.

Answer (score 8):

During my Masters, the project my supervisor was involved in was dealing in detecting and recognizing all kinds of different traffic signalization in a video sequences (e.g. road detection, road centerline detection, but also **traffic sign detection and recognition**). The video frames we were working on are in many ways similar to your example images.

While I personally didn't work on traffic signs, I think the best results were obtained by using the [**Viola-Jones Algorithm** (paper)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2F~viola%2FPubs%2FDetect%2FviolaJones_IJCV.pdf&ei=D3iKUP3OJYix0QXNx4G4Cw&usg=AFQjCNHv5ZMXrBGA2ETaBg6suywybnkoQg). In short, it is an algorithm that uses a cascade of *weak classifiers* (with accuracy just a bit higher than that of a random algorithm) to construct a *strong classifier* that is robust even in difficult tasks.

The project was called [MASTIF (Mapping and Assessing the State of Traffic InFrastructure)](http://www.zemris.fer.hr/~ssegvic/mastif/index_en.shtml) and did some really good work. Project's [publication page](http://www.zemris.fer.hr/~ssegvic/mastif/publications_en.shtml) could be really useful because it provides links to all the published papers related to the project. Just to give you an idea, let me single some of the publications out (in chronological order):

- [Karla Brkić, Axel Pinz, Siniša Šegvić: "Traffic sign detection as a component of an automated traffic infrastructure inventory system"](http://www.zemris.fer.hr/~ssegvic/pubs/oagm09.pdf)
- [A. Martinović, G. Glavaš, M. Juribašić, D. Sutić and Z. Kalafatić: "Real-time Detection and Recognition of Traffic Signs"](http://www.zemris.fer.hr/~ssegvic/mastif/pubs/martinovic10.pdf)
- [Igor Bonači, Ivan Kusalić, Ivan Kovaček, Zoran Kalafatić, Siniša Šegvić: "Addressing false alarms and localization inaccuracy in traffic sign detection and recognition"](http://www.zemris.fer.hr/~ssegvic/pubs/bonaci11cvww.pdf)

Once again, I didn't personally work on traffic signs, but I think you can find plenty of useful material here. Also, I would suggest going through cited references in the papers as they can be of help as well.

Answer (score 6):

Well, googling [`road way signs detection`](http://bit.ly/XpIZPw) gives you plenty of good papers on this topic.

Some uses color segmentation due peculiar blue,green,red colors etc.

Some apply Gaussian smoothing first, then canny edge detection and contour finding to extract the sign board.

Try following two links : [Link 1](http://hassan.shojania.com/pdf/Real-time%20traffic%20sign%20detection-Presentation.pdf), [Link 2](http://www.bartlab.org/Dr.%20Jackrit%27s%20Papers/ney/1.TRAFFIC_SIGN_Lorsakul_ISR.pdf)

Comment: dead links, unfortunately

Comment: Actually both the links works for me.

Comment: @CharlesB : The links are updated :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm definitely not an expert here but you can start with edge detection (such as canny), then hough transform to detect circles, rectangles, squares, or triangles (based on the sign ou want to detect), then you can do template matching or histogram matching, if the colors are distinct enough (over the candidates returned by the hough transform).

The first step (detecting the candidates using hough transform) is the harder step. I can think of many ways to try to detect whether that candidate is the sign or not. This is a fun problem. Enjoy solving it :)

By the way, I'm sure you can find good research articles that are highly related